# css property display works with setTimeout otherwise not

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

**PROBLEM SETTING**

I am working on a project which contain a lot of JavaScript files. The library i am using is Google closure library. I am calling a function, let say "**save()**" from a file (let say "**a.js**"), the definition of function save is in some other file say (let say "**b.js**"), before calling a function save, I set some overlay display to "**block**". In the first line of save function, I set its display to "**none**".

**Now Consider two scenarios now:**

i) `function save(){goog.style.setStyle(overlay, 'display', 'none');}`

ii) `function save(){setTimeout(function(){goog.style.setStyle(overlay, 'display', 'none');},50);}`

In first scenario, the overlay display is not set to none, but with timeout in second scenario its working. What is the reason behind it?

P.S: goog.style.setStyle is closure library function used to set style. goog.dom.getElementByClass is used to get that element.

Comment: Sounds like the element isn't on screen yet.  Hard to say without a more complete example.

Comment: Are you getting any error in the first scenario or it just fails silently? This can happen if the element is not yet created when you are applying the style(it should throw an error). Or it can be because some other code is changing the style after you changed it. `setTimeout` will make the code execute at the end of the current run loop which is helping you to get the desired result.

Comment: Try printing info with console.log() from your save() function.  That will confirm that it's getting called, and you can print the state of the element (whether it is visible, location, etc).